# Form checker not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm learning JavaScript and heard that `document.getElementbyId()` is quite useful.

So, I thought that I might make a form-checker that checks if the form field is blank.

[Here is the jsFiddle (for some reason it isn't displaying it correctly, you might want to make it a local file).](http://jsfiddle.net/cCnFS/1/)

For some reason the `alert()` calls are not showing.

Comment: Not an answer (learning javascript is great, keep going), but an alternative solution for the "real world" you should be aware of: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only testing if the textbox object is null. Not if the value in the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) is empty.

What you need is:

```
var LastName = document.getElementById('LastName');
if (LastName.value === '') {
    alert('Please enter a Last Name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName');
if (FirstName === '') {
```

`FirstName` is a DOMElement.  To get it's value, use `FirstName.value`.

```
if (FirstName.value === '') {
```